# More bit-twiddling: Efficiently implementing a binary search over a fixed-size array

Tags: c, optimization

Once again, I have a problem for which I would like to shave off nanoseconds.  I have a small, constant array and I would like to search it to see if a given number is a member*.

**Input**: A 64-bit number *n*.

**Output**: True if *n* is in the array, false if *n* is not.

What are good techniques for making binary searches fast, given the possibility to optimize for the specific elements and their distribution.

### Specifics

I have an array with around 136 members (though see below: there's some flexibility) to search.  The members are not equally distributed through the range: they cluster toward the beginning and end of the range.  The input numbers can be assumed to the chosen with uniform probability.  It's probably worthwhile to take advantage of this irregularity.

Here's a sample picture of the distribution for the 136-element array.  Note that *only 12 of the 136 elements* are between 1% and 99% of the range; the balance are below 1% or over 99%.

[image]
<sub>(source: [crg4.com](http://math.crg4.com/distribution.png))</sub>

I assume that branch misprediction will be the largest cost of any implementation.  I'd be happy to be proved wrong.

### Notes

*
Actually, I have two arrays.  Actually actually, I have a choice of what arrays to use: efficiency suggests that the first should have perhaps 10-40 members, while the second can have no more than (exactly) 136 members.  My problem gives real flexibility in selecting sizes, along with limited freedom to decide precisely which members to use.  If a method performs better with certain sizes or restrictions, please mention this because I may be able to use it.  All things equal, I'd prefer to have the second array as large as possible.  For reasons unrelated to the binary search I may need to reduce the size of the second array to <= 135 or <= 66 (this is related to the difficulty of determining the *input* number, which depends on the array selected).

Here's one of the possible arrays, if it helps in testing ideas.  (This pretty well reveals my purpose...!)  Don't jump to unwarranted conclusions on the basis of the first few members, though.

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 4807526976, 7778742049, 12586269025, 20365011074, 32951280099, 53316291173, 86267571272, 139583862445, 225851433717, 365435296162, 591286729879, 956722026041, 1548008755920, 2504730781961, 4052739537881, 6557470319842, 10610209857723, 17167680177565, 27777890035288, 44945570212853, 72723460248141, 117669030460994, 190392490709135, 308061521170129, 498454011879264, 806515533049393, 1304969544928657, 2111485077978050, 3416454622906707, 5527939700884757, 8944394323791464, 14472334024676221, 23416728348467685, 37889062373143906, 61305790721611591, 99194853094755497, 160500643816367088, 259695496911122585, 420196140727489673, 679891637638612258, 1100087778366101931, 1779979416004714189, 2880067194370816120, 4660046610375530309, 7540113804746346429, 9320093220751060618, 9999984858389672876, 10259680355300795461, 10358875208395550958, 10396764270768694864, 10411236604793371085, 10416764544494255842, 10418876029572233892, 10419682545105283285, 10419990606626453414, 10420108275656914408, 10420153221227127261, 10420170388907304826, 10420176946377624668, 10420179451108406629, 10420180407830432670, 10420180773265728832, 10420180912849591277, 10420180966165882450, 10420180986530893524, 10420180994309635573, 10420180997280850646, 10420180998415753816, 10420180998849248253, 10420180999014828394, 10420180999078074380, 10420180999102232197, 10420180999111459662, 10420180999114984240, 10420180999116330509, 10420180999116844738, 10420180999117041156, 10420180999117116181, 10420180999117144838, 10420180999117155784, 10420180999117159965, 10420180999117161562, 10420180999117162172, 10420180999117162405, 10420180999117162494, 10420180999117162528, 10420180999117162541, 10420180999117162546, 10420180999117162548
```

I will initially run the program on a Phenom II x4, but optimizations for other architectures are welcome.

Comment: People post images here all the time, can you not save it as JPEG or something?

Comment: It would help to tag this with the language you're working in

Comment: Does the array represent a set or a multiset? I.e., are duplicates allowed?

Comment: Tagged.  I imagine most ideas this low-level will be fairly portable.

Comment: Duplicates are not allowed.  (If they were, I'd remove them beforehand -- I have the array at compile time.)

Comment: If you have it at compile time can you just copy the array here?

Comment: @James: As discussed in the Notes section, I don't actually have one array but a collection of possible arrays that I could use, depending on how I set up the rest of the program.  I can post one as an example if you like.

Comment: @James: I was having trouble accessing my website to upload the picture.  Now I've managed and the picture should be visible.

Comment: "Don't jump to unwarranted conclusions on the basis of the first few members", ah, c'mon, Fibonacci sequences and the golden ratio are freaking *magical*. There must be some relatively simple transformation that will give you a laser-precision interpolation for those first few entries :-)

Comment: Notice that 9320093220751060618 is not a Fibonacci number. :)

Comment: @Charles: sure, but if you're hand-picking the array, then you control what ranges you special-case. `if (input < limit_of_magic) { return magical_fibonacci_optimization(input); } else { return normal_thing(input); }`

Comment: @Steve Jessop: So now you've reduced the problem (for small enough n) to that of deciding whether n is a Fibonacci number.  All we need to do for that is to make a lookup table and search it, using the methods [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5239055/341362), right?

Comment: @Charles: you *could*, but that question wasn't about Fibonacci numbers, it was about just any old S-shaped distribution ;-) The Fibonacci sequence is generated by dividing successive powers of phi by sqrt(5), a blatantly invertible function. So take `n = log(input * sqrt(5)) / log(phi)` and just look at the indexes either side of that in the array. +/-1 for "can't be bothered" errors. That's one logarithm, one floating point addition and one floating point division, which we're racing against our best array-searching technology. Dunno who wins, but surely worth trying.

Comment: Logs are expensive, do you really think that would be faster?

Comment: I don't care whether it's faster, I just care that it doesn't take very long to find out whether it's faster ;-). It might be possible to use a reduced-accuracy log, but that's beyond my knowledge of math libraries to figure out. And of course the log can be taken in whatever base is fastest to calculate (to sufficient accuracy) for a 64 bit integer.

Comment: Relevant: Yao, "Should Tables be Sorted?", Journal of the ACM, Vol 28, 1981.

Comment: Have you considered using a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) to quickly detect that an element is not in the array (and avoid the binary search)? This is likely to be a performance win if most searches are expected to produce "not in array" result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a very simple possible optimization, create a 256-entry lookup table for the most significant 8 bits of your 64 bit value. Each row of the table stores indexes in the actual array of the lower and upper bounds of values with those most significant 8 bits. You only need to search this region of the array.

If your array values were uniformly distributed, all the regions would be about the same length, and this wouldn't provide much gain (if any), it's not much different from an interpolation search. Since your values are so skewed, most of the 256 entries will point to very short regions (near the middle) which are fast to binary search, or even 0-sized regions. 2 or 3 entries at each end will point to much larger regions of the array, which then will take relatively longer to search through (almost as long as a binary search of the whole array). Since your inputs are uniformly distributed, the average time spent searching will be reduced, and hopefully this reduction is greater than the cost of the initial lookup. Your worst-case might well end up slower, though.

To refine this, you might have a 2-level lookup table on 4 bits at a time. The first level either says "search between these indices", or else "look up the next 4 significant bits in this second-level table". The former is fine for middling values, where 16 times the value-range still corresponds to a very small index-range, and so is still quick to search. The latter would be for the ends of the range where the search space is larger. Total size of tables would be smaller, which may or may not give better performance due to better caching of less data. The tables themselves could be generated at runtime, or at compile-time if you're willing to generate C code once the array values are known. You could even code the lookup table as a giant switch-statement from hell, just to see if it speeds things up or not.

If you haven't already, you should also benchmark an interpolation search rather than a simple binary chop once you start searching in the array.

Note that I've worked to reduce the number of comparisons made in the binary search, rather than specifically the number of branch mispredictions. The two are sort of proportional anyway - you can't avoid that each time you halve the possibilities in a binary search, you'll get a misprediction in something like 50% of cases. If you really wanted to minimize mispredictions, then a *linear* search guarantees only one misprediction per lookup (the one that breaks the loop). That ain't faster in general, but you could experiment to see whether there's a size for the remaining array to be searched, below which you should switch to a linear search, perhaps unrolled, perhaps fully unrolled. There may be some other much cleverer hybrid linear/binary search that can be tuned for the relative cost of a successful vs. unsuccessful comparison, but if so I don't know it.

Comment: I like this idea.  Of course most of the entries will be empty since 136 is smaller than 256 and the numbers cluster.  In my example 240 entries have no members so the search is done at that point.

Comment: @Charles: yes, I'd guess that the more 0-sized regions you have, the more likely it is that a smaller lookup table will give you just as good a region to search in almost all cases. I picked 256 arbitrarily, I'd recommend writing the code such that it's easy to change ;-)

Comment: I tend to like the 0-sized regions: when I get those I'm done immediately.  Do you think that a switch table would be an efficient way to code this?  I'm not sure how those are converted to asm these days.

Comment: I think a switch might be more efficient, again enough to try if you're desperate. Almost certainly larger code, which counts against, but the compiler can emit a jump table if it wants, or something even more clever (e.g. a folding operation to cut down the possibilities prior to a jump table, or an optimized sequence of comparisons and branches). Crucially it's the compiler that gets to guess which will be fastest, and the compiler has a far stronger opinion that I do what will be fast. Even when it's wrong, at least it's wrong for sound reasons, and sometimes it's scarily right.

Answer (score 3):

Since you know the array data at compile time, you might consider using a [hash](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html) instead of a binary search. A carefully chosen hash could be faster, especially if you can find a simple hash function that is collision-free for your data, and fits within your memory constraints.

**Edit: to further explain...**

You hash the 64-bit value to a smaller value, which is an index into an array. In your case, you would aim to have a collision-free hash, so your array would just be an array of a) for hits, the 1 valid value that hashes to that array index, or b) for misses, an invalid value.

You pick the hash function that suits your purposes. In your case, the main parameters are:

- the size of the hash output, which determines the size of the array, and also affects the probability of a collision.
- a function which is as simple (fast) as possible.
- a function which doesn't produce collisions.

Assuming no collisions, you use it at run-time as follows:

1. Hash your input.
2. Use the resulting hash value to index into your array.
3. Test whether the array value matches your input.

If your hash function produces collisions, your choices are:

- Make your hash output bigger, to reduce the chance of collisions.
- Try to find a different hash function that doesn't produce collisions with your particular data set.
- Make an array of something slightly more complicated, like a linked list of valid 64-bit inputs that hash to that value. But this slows you down, since step 3 above becomes more complicated: you have to scan a linked list, rather than just testing a single value.

Comment: I'm not clear on how this would help.  I hash the input from a 64-bit value to (presumably) a smaller value, then check if the value is the same as the hashed value of one of my array members (and if so, check if the original number actually corresponds).  But then I'm right back in my starting position: I have a number and I want to check if it's on a small list.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I'll look this over tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

If all you're interested in is member/not-member, rather than location, you *could* eliminate some conditional branches with the following arrangement:

```
bool b = false;
b |= (n == x[i]);
b |= (n == x[i+1]);
// ... etc. ...
```

Clearly, you probably don't want to do this for all 136 entries.  But there may be a sweet spot where you are able to mix a coarse-grained binary search to first locate which batch of e.g. 4 elements `n` could be in, and then switch to the above approach.

Comment: Correct, all I care about is whether the number is a member or not.

Comment: You'd want to check the assembly to be sure whether or not `b |= (n == x[i]);` actually has a branch in it anyway...

Comment: @Steve: True (FWIW, it didn't in my little mock-up using -O3 with GCC 4.1.2 on x86).

Answer (score 1):

A normal binary search would iterate at most log_2(n) times.  Each iteration would typically have three comparisons (Are we done?  Is the number higher?  Is it lower?).  That's three chances to fail branch prediction on each iteration.

If you unrolled the binary search (which is feasible because your array is so small and the values are known ahead of time), you could eliminate the "are we done?" comparisons, and your typical base would go from 3*log_2(n) to 2*log_2(n).  This is fewer instructions executed and fewer chances for a missed branch prediction.  But it's also more total instructions (and thus less cache friendly).  You'd have to profile to see if this would help on balance.

You could write a quick program to generate the unrolled search function rather than unrolling it by hand.

Perhaps profile-guided optimization on the unrolled search could help further by taking advantage of the uneven distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. At first I thought this were one of the many problems that can be most efficiently be handled by a red-black tree mapping ascending values to indices.

*However*, you have pointed out that the distribution is so non-uniform. If we go at this first from the human perspective: *what would a human do*, he/she would probably first check whether the given value is below the 0.01 quantile, then whether it is above the 0.99 quantile, and by this strategy already have limited the search space by 49/50th only having done 2 comparisons.

- Further iterations in the 0.01-0.99 range are rare (these numbers are the 0...1 mapping of the e.g. 64bit value-space)
- Further iterations in the 0.0-0.01 and 0.99-1.0 range dont need to go deep because they are already close to the correct value.

So, how can we generalize this? We dont need to. You have noticed that 0.0-0.01 is frequent and 0.99-1.0 of the value-space is frequent; **but** this is probably not the case in the second iteration and definitely not the case in the third iteration (you will not find the same distribution inside the 0.0-0.01-range of values as you did in the complete range).

I would do it like this: A jumptable with 3 targets dependent on in which of the 3 regions the value lies, then red-black-trees for each of the regions.

Comment: Why a red-black tree in preference to for example an AVL tree? There will be no insertions/removals, and very many lookups, so a more balanced tree would seem more likely to be faster.

Comment: In practice red-black and avl behave almost the same, avl is harder to implement tho might have slightly better balance.

Comment: Well, a basic binary chop is easier to implement than either, and the questioner has already rejected that. Not that I'm convinced even a perfectly balanced tree would beat a binary search for speed anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Since there are 136 members only, on a newish PC I would do a brute force search using 128-bit instructions and prefetch.

If there were thousands of members, I would echo Steve Jessop's idea of a 256-entry lookup table above, but with a function f(x) applied to the lookup value which purpose is to evenly distribute the members into 256 buckets.

f(x) could be some kind of polynomial, similar to "smoothstep" from the world of graphics but perhaps not as smooth.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting alternative is to use a modified (bidirectional) version of linear search.

The pseudocode is easier than the code:

```
if the value is greater than or equal to 2^63
    linear search from middle to end
otherwise (if the value is less than 2^63)
    linear search from middle to beginning (must go in reverse direction)
```

My code is pretty hacky, but you can make it look more elegant:

```
int in_set(unsigned long long value)
{
    const unsigned long long max_bit_mask = (1 << 63);

    if(value & max_bit_mask) //if max bit is set, use linear search from middle (50% probability)
    {
        unsigned long long *ullp = data + 91; //WARNING: ullp should point to data + 92 on first dereference due to prefix increment
        while(*++ullp < value); //FIXME: array must be capped with ULLONG_MAX on the right
        return *ullp == value; //&& ullp != right_sentinel
    }

    //otherwise use reverse linear search from middle

    unsigned long long *ullp = data + 92; //WARNING: ullp should point to data + 91 on first dereference due to prefix decrement
    while(*--ullp > value); //WARNING: array must be capped with zero on the left
    return *ullp == value; //&& ullp != left_sentinel
}
```

For random inputs to this particular Fibonacci distribution array, the code will be a O(1) algorithm on average (O(k) in the worst case where k is the table size).

You can use Steve Jessop's lookup table strategy to cache the index of the element closest to the center of the array with a particular 8 bit signature, but it might make the code slower, since you are adding an extra O(1) time factor with extra branch misprediction.

```
const int lookup_table[256] = {/*...*/};

unsigned long long *ullp = data + lookup[value >> 56];

//if, while, and returns as before
```

One implementation issue with this strategy is you have to pad with the minimum and maximum values on the left and right sides of the array or errors will happen eventually (in this case 0 and ULLONG_MAX). For zero, this isn't a problem, but for ULLONG_MAX the value is not in the set and thus additional logic is required. In this particular case sentinel values must be used and properly accounted for.

edit: the time complexity is O(1) in the average case because each advance of the cursor has a ~40% (1/phi^2) chance of returning, the expected cost is the summation of n/phi^(n+1) for n >= 1, which equates to 1/(phi-1)^2 (~2.6 cursor advances)

edit2: this code should have far less branch misprediction than a binary search and should be faster on average as long as queries have "uniform integer distribution".